# Issues with Hex.encodeHexString(byte[] hexStringByteArray);

Tags: hex, apache-commons-codec

I was used Hex.encodeHexString(byte[] hexStringByteArray); api for convert byte array to String but in two different situations not able to get the excepted values.

Excepted String tcpPort = "1443";

In byte array [5,-93] --> In Hex String : 05a3

```
byte[] value1 = new byte[]{[5, -93]}; 
String tcpPort1 = Hex.encodeHexString(value1); // Incorrect value 05a3
```

Excepted String bufferSize = "0578";

In byte array [[5, 120] --> In Hex String : 0578

```
String bufferSize = "0578"; // in byte array [5,120]
byte[] value2 = new byte[]{[5, 120]}; 

String bufferSize = Hex.encodeHexString(value1); --- Correct value 0578
```

1 is incorrect and 2 is correct. Please help on this. I have to correct both values in same way.

Comment: Please make use of code formatting

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).